# How to include additional compiler arguments when using mxmlc ant task?

Tags: apache-flex, ant, service, mxmlc

Flex Builder allows additional compiler arguments to be set in the compiler options, under properties. It sets the argument;

`-services ".../services-config.xml"`

Is there a way to set the same argument when using the ant task mxmlc?

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set it as an attribute on the mxmlc task:

```
<mxmlc services="../services-config.xml"/>
```

Comment: There is no services attribute on the mxmlc ant tasks.  I found that I had to fall back on the mxml.exe using the <exec> tasks as stated below

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of.

You could always use the  task with  subnodes if you still are unable to find it in the docs.

Example:

```
<exec executable="${mxmlc.exe}" dir="${basedir}">
    <arg line="-source-path '${flex2sdk.locale.dir}'" />
    <arg line="-locale en_US" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues with the services attribute not being available for use in the ant tasks so I added the  option to fix the problem:

```
 <mxmlc file="path" output="path to output" >
       <compiler.services>${path-to-services}</compiler.services>
       <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
       <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
       <compiler.debug>false</compiler.debug>
       <compiler.context-root>/PATWeb</compiler.context-root>
 </mxmlc>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished by the following:

```
<target name="compileApp">
<mxmlc file="src/app.mxml" 
...other options
services="[path to your services-config.xml]" 
context-root="[path to where your gateway file is]">
...
</target>
```

This is how we are currently building the mxml app... which means Christophe was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the compiler options are available as either attributes or tags for the `mxmlc` task, however some options are missing, or work in somewhat unexpected way. Worst thing is lack of proper documentation for the flex Ant tasks.
Sometimes I find it easier to do this:

```
<mxmlc file="Main.as" output="bin/app.swf">
    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/flex-config.xml" />
    <load-config filename="build/config.xml" />
</mxmlc>
```

And then specify all the options I want in build/config.xml, at least the syntax is [documented better](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67670-7ff2.html), and you can always use `flex-config.xml` or `air-config.xml` from your SDK as a (well-commented) sample.